# Pandas groupby and filter with multiple conditions

Tags: pandas, group-by

```
        Date    Symbol   Open   High    Low  Close
0 2023-05-31  GEDIK.IS   7.90   8.01   7.77   7.87
1 2023-06-01  GEDIK.IS   7.92   8.20   7.89   8.14
2 2023-05-31  MIPAZ.IS   7.87   7.90   7.74   7.84
3 2023-06-01  MIPAZ.IS   7.84   8.06   7.80   8.05
4 2023-05-31  SUNTK.IS  36.20  37.52  35.48  37.00
5 2023-06-01  SUNTK.IS  37.20  38.30  36.60  38.30
6 2023-05-31  VANGD.IS   7.26   7.36   6.95   7.08
7 2023-06-01  VANGD.IS   7.09   7.63   6.92   7.48
```

I want to filter stocks from this dataframe where current day (06-01) has a positive candle (Close>Open) and creates a LL with the previous day.
In this example it should return VANGD only.
I can filter LLs by

```
df.groupby(['Symbol']).apply(lambda x: x[x["Low"] > x["Low"].shift(-1)])
```

However this only returns first row of the matching stock. I need to get entire group.

```
                 Date    Symbol  Open  High   Low  Close
Symbol
VANGD.IS 6 2023-05-31  VANGD.IS  7.26  7.36  6.95   7.08
```

Than I can filter stocks with positive candle.
Also there are only 4 stocks in this example. Keep in mind that original df have nearly 500 stocks to be filtered.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is `LLs` ?

Comment: Lower Low. Current days Low is < than the previous days Low.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to extract the matching Symbol names then `.isin()` to find all corresponding rows.

If the Symbols are all adjacent, you can replace the `.groupby().apply` by also comparing the shifted Symbol:

```
LLs = df.loc[
   (df['Symbol'] == df['Symbol'].shift(-1)) & 
   (df['Low'] > df['Low'].shift(-1)), 
   'Symbol'
]

df[df['Symbol'].isin(LLs)]
```

```
        Date    Symbol  Open  High   Low  Close
6 2023-05-31  VANGD.IS  7.26  7.36  6.95   7.08
7 2023-06-01  VANGD.IS  7.09  7.63  6.92   7.48
```